# Creating new JSON objects from larger PowerShell objects

Tags: json, powershell

From a large PowerShell Object that I have retrieved via an Invoke-RestMethod, I am looking to shrink this down to select attributes and create a new (smaller) object that I can then convert into a JSON array.

Sample set courtesy of '[The Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/08/playing-with-json-and-powershell/)':

```
$request = 'http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?inc=aliases&fmt=json'
$output = Invoke-WebRequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json
$output
```

Gives me:

```
type-id        : e431f5f6-b5d2-343d-8b36-72607fffb74b
name           : Nirvana
ipis           : {}
disambiguation : 90s US grunge band
country        : US
life-span      : @{end=1994-04-05; ended=True; begin=1988-01}
sort-name      : Nirvana
isnis          : {0000000123486830}
aliases        : {@{name=Nirvana US; type-id=; sort-name=Nirvana US; end=; 
begin=; primary=; type=; locale=; ended=False}}
begin_area     : @{name=Aberdeen; disambiguation=; sort-name=Aberdeen; 
id=a640b45c-c173-49b1-8030-973603e895b5}
area           : @{sort-name=United States; id=489ce91b-6658-3307-9877-795b68554c98; iso-3166-1-codes=System.Object[]; disambiguation=; name=United States}
type           : Group
id             : 5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da
end_area       : 
gender         : 
gender-id      :
```

If I use the select option on the root-level attributes, this works as expected:

```
$request = 'http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-
a69a8278c7da?inc=aliases&fmt=json'
$output = Invoke-WebRequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json
$output | select name, disambiguation | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

```
{
    "name":  "Nirvana",
    "disambiguation":  "90s US grunge band"
}
```

But if I try to add one of the nested attributes, it doesn't work as I'd hope...

```
$output | select name, disambiguation, area.sortname | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "name":  "Nirvana",
    "disambiguation":  "90s US grunge band",
    "area.sort-name":  null # <-- Expect "United States"
}
```

What I'd like to see:

```
{
    "name":  "Nirvana",
    "disambiguation":  "90s US grunge band",
    "area":  {
        "sort-name":  "United States"
    }
}
```

I've also tried expanding the array, but this seems to lose my root level fields which I want to retain:

```
$output | select -expand area | select name, disambiguation, sort-name | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "name":  "United States", # <-- Taken from the area.name value
    "disambiguation":  "",    # <-- Lost when expanding
    "sort-name":  "United States"
}
```

Any suggestions/pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: `select name, @{Name='sort-name'; Expression={$_.area.sort-name}}`, it's a calculated property, and how you generate 'virtual' properties when it's not as straightforward as selecting an existing property name directly.

Comment: Ahh sensational! That's it!  Thanks heaps! Just needed to put brackets around the `sort-name` so the end (working) result was:
`select name, @{Name='sort-name'; Expression={$_.area.{sort-name}}}`

Comment: @Arrjo: Put that as an answer and accept the answer later.

Comment: You can also use the -depth parameter in convertto-json to get nested properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided by TessellatingHeckler

```
select name, @{Name='sort-name'; Expression={$_.area.{sort-name}}}
```