# Loading file with array of hashtables failing

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable, powershell-4.0

Leading on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749278/creating-new-json-objects-from-larger-powershell-objects/43781995), I've been using arrays and hashtables as variables to get values from nested data structures. e.g. Defining `$fields` and feeding it into a `select` operator:

```bsh
$request = 'http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?inc=aliases&fmt=json'
$output = Invoke-WebRequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json
$fields = "name", 
          @{Name='begin'; Expression={$_.{life-span}.begin}},
          @{Name='end'; Expression={$_.{life-span}.end}}
$output | select $fields
```

Giving me:

```
name                         begin                           end
----                         -----                           ---
Nirvana                      1988-01                         1994-04-05
```

However, if I defined the array as a JSON structure for importing (bandFields.json)

```json
{
    "fields": [
        "name",
        {
            "Name": "begin",
            "Expression": "{$_.{life-span}.begin}"
        }, {
            "Name": "end",
            "Expression": "{$_.{life-span}.end}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And try to import it a an array (similar to what I'd previously manually specified):

```bsh
$request = 'http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?inc=aliases&fmt=json'
$output  = Invoke-WebRequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json

$runConf = Get-Content -Raw -Path bandFields.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$fields  = $runConf.fields

$output | select $fields
```

And I get this:

> select : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.

Comment: I've just imported your json with `$runConf = Get-Content -Raw -Path bandFields.json | ConvertFrom-Json`, so no idea what is wrong

Comment: The problem is that $fields is now a PSObject, not an Array. Within the object the field named "name" is also getting confused with the other name properties. It's a very unusual way to approach this sort of thing and i'd be tempted to revise it entirely.